# Laplace transform approximation

Tags: approximation, laplace-transform

In the Wigner-Weisskopf theory of spontaneous decay, the Laplace transform for the amplitude is found to be $$L(s)=\frac{1}{s+i\omega+G(s)}$$ where $G(s)$ is a complex function. $L(s)$ has a pole at $s=-i\omega-G(s)$ and so the approximation is made that $G(s)$ can be replaced with $G(s=-i\omega)=\frac{1}{2}\Gamma+iS$ provided that $G(s)$ is slowly varying around $s=-i\omega$ and that $\Gamma\ll\omega$.

I don't understand this second condition; why must it not be the case that $S\ll\omega$ as well? Otherwise, at $s=-i\omega$, the denominator would still be large, and there may exist some other $s$ where it is much smaller. I must be wrong because it turns out that $S$ diverges and yet the theory still works, but I can't see why.

Comment: I don't know the physics. $S$ will only effect the frequency. $\Gamma$ will effect the rate of decay. $L(s) \approx \frac{1}{s+i\omega+\frac{1}{2}\Gamma+iS} \longrightarrow e^{-i(\omega+S)}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\Gamma}$. From the paper I skimmed it seems there are multiple $G(s)$ functions consequently multiple $S$ values. The central frequency is $\omega$. The condition $\Gamma\ll\omega$ allows multiple oscillations to occur before the signal decays. (Equation 3.31 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/9909043.pdf)

Comment: Forgot the $t$. $L(s) \approx \frac{1}{s+i\omega+\frac{1}{2}\Gamma+iS} \longrightarrow e^{-i(\omega+S)t}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\Gamma t}$